# Viking GPS editor/viewer: how to scroll the map while entering points in a track?

Tags: geolocation

I just discovered the (great) [Viking](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/viking/index.php?title=Main_Page) application for editing and viewing GPS tracks.

I am struggling to find a way to scroll the map while I am editing?adding points to a track or a route, like in the following case:

[image]

I know I can click on the "four arrow" symbol and then move the map, but this will exit the track editing mode --- I have to select "extend track" to continue each time.

I am sure there should be a better method, but I am unable to find it.

Is there a way to scroll the map while in track editing mode?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted the question, I found the answer in the [here](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/viking/index.php?title=User_Interface_Ideas).

**Mid-click** will center the map again and allow you to continue inputting the track; scrolling with the mouse wheel will change the zoom level.